# How is Gimli from Lord of the Rings connected to the dwarf in The Hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, desolation-of-smaug

In *The Hobbit: the Desolation of Smaug*, when the dwarves get captured in the forest by the elves, Legolas takes a photo from one of the dwarves, and the dwarf states that’s Gimli. I'm aware who that is from Lord of the Rings, but how do they connect to each other?

Comment: It's not a photo (no cameras). You might call the individual drawings *portraits*, or *portrait miniatures*. Miniatures used to be quite common, before cameras.

Comment: He says "it's my wee lad" I assumed that means his son.

Answer (score 43):

**TL;DR: Gimli (depicted in the locket, and from *The Lord Of The Rings*) is the son of Glóin (in *The Hobbit*).**

---

[Glóin](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gloin) is the dwarf that shows Legolas the locket.

[image: Glóin]

The locket depicts his [wife](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gimli's_mother) and son, [Gimli](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gimli) - the same Gimli of the *Lord of the Rings*.

[image: locket]

> **Glóin:** Give it back, that's private!
>
> **Legolas:**  Who is this? Your brother?
>
> **Glóin:** That is my wife.
>
> **Legolas:** And what is this horrid creature, goblin mutant?
>
> **Glóin:** That's me wee lad, Gimli.

In *The Fellowship of the Ring*, Gimli is mentioned specifically as "the son of Glóin".

> “For the rest, they shall represent the other Free Peoples of the World: Elves, Dwarves, and Men, Legolas shall be for the Elves; and **Gimli son of Glóin** for the Dwarves. They are willing to go at least to the passes of the Mountains, and maybe beyond. For Men you shall have Aragorn son of Arathorn, for the Ring of Isildur concerns him closely”

Comment: "Wee lad" How young is Gimli in that picture, sporting the full facial hair and all?

Comment: @agweber We are speaking of *dwarves* not humans! I have always imagined dwarves be born with all the facial hair already in place...

Comment: Just making trouble, @agweber: How do you know that the one with the beard *isn't* his wife? We never meet any Dwarven women; they could be bearded for all we know... and curled hair and square necklines haven't always been restricted to women.

Comment: @keshlam to be fair, Gloin identifies his wife as Legolas looks at the image in the left side of the locket.

Comment: Adding to that, in the LOTR-movieseries Gimli muses on how people think there are no Dwarven women precisely BECAUSE Dwarven women have as much beard as the men.

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh: When talking of the movies, all that Gimli talks about is how people think there are no Dwarven women, and *Aragorn* makes a gesture about "probably because of their beards" to make Eowyn laugh -- but we are not told whether Aragorn is serious, or even knows.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. Still, it already gave indication that Dwarven women (probably) have beards.

Comment: I haven't seen the film yet so I have no opinion; just pointing out that the trope of bearded drawrven women is not uncommon in other fantasy worlds. (Usually played for laughs; best version of that I've seen was of course Sargent Cheery in Pratchett's _Diskworld_ books.)

Comment: @keshlam, we see Dwarf women at the start of "An Unexpected Journey". Also, Thorin son of Thrain, has a sister named Dis, according to a family tree.

Comment: There are dwarven women in Dale at the beginning of the first film.  They do have thin, whispy hair on their chins, but nothing approaching the full beards of the male dwarves.

Answer (score 1):

Gimli, Son of Gloin

He's also Balin's cousin(?)

Comment: This seems very brief. Could you flesh it out with something that actually proves your assertion?

Comment: @Richard Balin and Dwalin are sons of Fundin who is brother of Groin the father of Oin and Gloin.  Therefore Gimli and Balin are 1st cousins once removed.

Comment: Balin is also the brother of Dwalin. Later, Balin visits Bilbo in Bag End, and eventually goes to Moria.